# resource available output parent resource rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, nested-resources

I have this in my routes.rb

```
resources :users, :path => "/", :only => [:show] do
  resources :collections, :controller => 'users/collections'
end
```

Why can I access to collections resources from:

```
http://localhost:3000/en/collections
```

if this resouce this inside users?

I want that `collection resource` only is enable inside:

```
http://localhost:3000/en/users/collections
```

This is my routes:

```
user_collections GET    (/:locale)/:user_id/collections(.:format)          users/collections#index
                         POST   (/:locale)/:user_id/collections(.:format)          users/collections#create
     new_user_collection GET    (/:locale)/:user_id/collections/new(.:format)      users/collections#new
    edit_user_collection GET    (/:locale)/:user_id/collections/:id/edit(.:format) users/collections#edit
         user_collection GET    (/:locale)/:user_id/collections/:id(.:format)      users/collections#show
                         PUT    (/:locale)/:user_id/collections/:id(.:format)      users/collections#update
                         DELETE (/:locale)/:user_id/collections/:id(.:format)      users/collections#destroy
```

How can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: Did you restart your app after changing your routes?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted my server after changing routes. I'm using rails 3.2.

Comment: do you need that :path => "/" ?

Comment: This is the problem, if I remove `:path => "/"` My url is very long. I have now `http://localhost:3000/en/kevin29/collections` but If I remove `:path => "/"` I have this: `http://localhost:3000/en/users/kevin29/collections` I want remove the `users` prefix!

Comment: Are you sure accessing `/en/collections` triggers collections#index? I think it has to trigger users#show, passing the string `collections` as id in params.

Comment: Yes I understand, but I have not an user named **collection** in my db. I must get an error... if the user collection is not found in database...

Comment: Show us the `params` from your log during accessing `/en/collections`

Comment: Sorry for delay @jdoe. The params  `--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
action: index
controller: users/collections 
user_id: en` the problem is that `en` is taken as a `user_id`. How can I fix this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
resources :users, :only => [:show] do
  resources :collections, :controller => 'users/collections'
end
```

Comment: With this solution I have a long url sth like: `http://localhost:3000/en/users/kevin29/collections` I want this url `http://localhost:3000/en/kevin29/collections` Thank you!